# Play Framework e AJAX (SPA)

Tags: ajax, play-framework, single-page-application

É possível desenvolver SPA com o Play? Alguém já teve essa experiência e tem algo a relatar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O play utiliza o sbt como ferramenta, ele tem vários plugins de compilação para SPA, single page application, como minificador de javascript compilador less sacss coffee e para ferramentas de front ent como bower e grunt. 
Sua arquitetura por padrão é stateless então fica fácil desenvolver a parte da API, ele tem configuração de rotas e suporte a json, e xml.

Tenho uma aplicação em produção sendo desenvolvida para ele.

--- em breve atualizo com melhor qualidade a resposta e referencias --